# Regex start matching from last occurence

Tags: regex

I have a html code:

```
<a href="localhost/1153,Test">  <img src="test.jpg">
(...)
<a href="localhost/1191,Test8">  <img src="test2.jpg">
(...)
<a href="localhost/9838,Test">  <img src="13.gif">
(...)
```

want to match a value before gif, in this example 9838. No matter how I try, I end up with first match (1153). How to match "backwards" from a known pattern?

Comment: try look ahead http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your contribution. Can you tell me how to get this value in C# from a totally malformed html? I don't want to parse HTML, I just want to extract this particular number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d*(?=,.*\.gif)
```

This matches the first occurence of digits before

```
[comma][other text][.gif]
```

You can test this [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: Thank you, can you explain why I get 6 matches in RegexBuddy but only one in RegExr?

Comment: It probably matches across newlines, so the first number is matched on the last occurrence. Use a nongreedy match or exclude newlines from the skip expression.

Comment: Im sorry im not sure but try this two links aswell both regex testers and both get same result: http://www.myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab, http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Tripleee- of course you're right, it's too hot to focus. Srb- thank you for a elegant solution: it looks great and works flawlessly. It's time to learn about lookaround, thank you!

Comment: No worries glad I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can do

```
Match theMatch = Regex.Match(source, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

which would start matching from the end.

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
<a href="localhost\/(\d+),Test\d*">  <img src="\w+\.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regex for this, it would be good to have some boundary conditions; what more or less similar pieces of text should not be matched?

Having said that, I might go for something like

```
(\d+)[^"\d]+"[^"]+"[^"\d]+\d+\.gif
```

and extract the first parenthesized submatch (assuming `[^\d]` matches neither newlines nor digits in your language; I am not too familiar with it).