# How to extract matched line of a multiline record in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have a multi-line field in this [Fiddle of Oracle 11g table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2f62/2). Using SQL, how can I extract the last line that matches 'Export'. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807938/regex-start-matching-from-last-occurence) helps with the `regex` for the last occurrence but I'm still not getting my desired results.

**Desired Results**

`1,[27-SEP-12] NOT for export`

`2,[27-SEP-12] OK for export`

Comment: Can't you fix the data so each line is in a separate record?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This was converted data at customer's request. At one time they were in separate records. Customer wanted all in a newer column with more column width. Now a third party needs information as if it were in the old table....

Comment: I'm aware, this is what happens when parties to a project are unaware of a change to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  customer_id,
  regexp_substr(exp_comment,'.*'||chr(10)||'(.*Export)', 1, 1, 'n', 1) as export
from export_comments
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2f62/15)

Comment: Egor, thanks for the response. I'm using Oracle's specs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm to help explain what is happening. What does the final 1 just before the closing parenthesis do?

Comment: You are looking at Oracle 10 docs.  Last parameter appeared in Oracle 11.